# Why isn't column data for a table visible when viewing data?

Tags: powerapps, common-data-service, dataverse

I added some custom columns to a table and then imported data to the Dataverse database table from an Excel file.  When I choose *Data>Edit Data In Excel*, all of the imported data is visible in Excel.  When just clicking on the Data option, however, only the "ID" and "Created On" columns are displayed.  Also, when clicking on a row and clicking on the *Edit Record* button, those same "ID" and "Created On" columns are the only ones that are visible.

How do you view data in a Dataverse table (other than viewing in Excel)?

[Screenshot of the empty Dataverse table in the web UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AFikV.png)

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of ways to make sure that you can see the data you want.

#1 Make a new "Entity Form"

- the Form will allow you to insert and update data in the table

go to Tables > your_table > Forms

[image]

choose main form

[image]

once you create, save, and publish your form it will the same layout shown to you when you go to edit individual entries in the table
-- this is one form I made

[image]

-- same view when I edit a single table row

go to Tables > your_table > Data > choose the record and then hit edit record at top

[image]

and then you will be taken to a screen that will allow you to edit that row

[image]

#2 Make a new table "View"

- the View will be used to display they data that you designate when building it

go to Tables > your_table > Views > make a new view or update default one

I would recommend updating the "Active your_tableName" view that is provided by default.

I've already updated mine so it's called Approved ERG Groups.

[image]

Once you've made your View, go to Data tab and that view along with any other will now be choices to display table data from the drop down in top right corner.

[image]

Hope that helps you out.

Happy Building.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use the select view setting to show the custom values from the drop down to see your custom values:

[image]